# SQLmap over uni wifi

Tags: sql-injection, kali-linux

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this question but I'll give it a shot! I was playing around with Kali and SQLmap. I was just scanning some sites nothing serious. When I was doing this I was logged in on my University's wifi network. Now the problem I have just got an email for a meeting with someone. Now is my question if they're able to see what I've done wit SQLmap?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they can see what you did. They will be able to see what sites you were hitting and that you were sending SQL injection code.

You have likely violated your Acceptable Use policies at a minimum, and possibly committed a crime (depending on your jurisdiction).

Be very open and honest and ask for help in trying to understand how you can stay in compliance in the future.

Answer (score -1):

The first thing when playing around security is to hide yourself :)

You would not go to rob the bank just for testing ? lol

And yes, they MAY have seen something wrong :
- with a remote control and view software that they would have installed
- by analyzing the network traffic and seeing connection attempts to their databases
- by having received alerts from a networks intrusion detection system (NIDS)

But they also MAY only have doubts and would like to know more...

Be careful :)

Comment: The first thing when "playing" with security is to ASK PERMISSION.

Comment: The thing is that the scan was targeted to a random website, not to the uni servers.